# Python decode AMF response

Tags: python, amf

I'm making a request in python to a web service which returns AMF. I don't know if it's AMF0 or AMF3 yet.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
>>> r.text
u'\x00\x03...'
```

([Full data here](http://pastebin.com/sdZnU8Ds))

How can I take `r.text` and convert it to a python object or similar? I found [amfast](http://code.google.com/p/amfast/) but it's `Decoder` class returns a `3.131513074181806e-294` assuming AMF0 and `None` for AMF3. (Both incorrect)

```
from amfast.decoder import Decoder
decoder = Decoder(amf3=False)
obj = decoder.decode(StringIO.StringIO(r.text))
```

Comment: Can you post the amfast decoding code?

Comment: Edited question to include decoding code.

Comment: Jake, reading the docs suggests that Decoder.decode expects a string. Can you try it without the StringIO call?

Comment: Yes, raises an error that the string has no method `read()`. Also tried using `r.raw` (is file-like) - same outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems with your code, the first is using `r.text` to return binary data. Use `r.content` instead. The second problem is using `decoder.decode` method, which decodes one object and not a packet. Use `decoder.decode_packet` instead.

```
from amfast.decoder import Decoder
decoder = Decoder(amf3=True)
obj = decoder.decode_packet(r.content)
```

Using Pyamf works as well, using `r.content`.

Answer (score 4):

have u tried PyAMF.

```
from pyamf import remoting
remoting.decode(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get `pyamf.DecodeError: Unsupported ActionScript type`

Comment: worked for me:     remoting.decode(r.content) in the case. Unsupported ActionScript type is probably because you are not passing the right bytes into it (r.content)